# Error with argument 'account_name' when using fsspec

Tags: python-3.x, fsspec

I am using fsspec (version 2022.2.0) to read csv files from ADLS Gen 2 into a pandas dataframe in databricks. A few months ago, the code started to fail with no change in the code. The line in the code is:

```
storage_options={'account_name': <storage_name>, 'account_key': <my_access_token>}

my_df = pd.read_csv(filepath, storage_options = storage_options, sep=",", skiprows = 1, usecols = my_cols)
```

The error message is:

```
type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'account_name'
```

I have updated the version of fsspec, with no change in the error. Is there anything else I could try to fix the issue?

Thank you,
T